# ContentType matching query does not exist

Tags: django, content-type

I recently attempted to load some fixtures into my database. When I run the server and load various pages though I get the error:

```
Caught DoesNotExist while rendering: ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

I've tried running syncdb, and resetting each of the apps individually, but haven't had any luck. How do I make this error go away?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look inside the fixture, each fixture has three root fields: the PK, the `fields` (which is a set of fields for the PK'th entry in that table), and a `model`, which contains the appname.modelname, from which the ORM derives the table information.

It is that appname.modelname that Django looks up, via the ContentType engine, to figure out which table to put your data into.

Your friend has given you at least one fixture in which the content of the `model` field does not match any actual model in your database.  This may be a misspelling, a misunderstanding, a change of model or application name, or any number of faults.  But the fixture does not correspond to any model in your project, and the fixture importer is telling you so, by saying it cannot match the model's designated name with any names in the projects ContentType table.

The fix may be as simple as figuring out what the table is supposed to have as a ContentType, then opening up the fixture and doing a mass search-and-replace on the `model:` line.

EDIT:

This is a long (long!) overdue edit.  If you're about to `dumpdata` that contains generic data or references to generic tables elsewhere, you *must* (I really can't emphasize how much you *must*) learn the `dumpdata --natural` flag.  Rather than save contentType information by number, it will save it by name, making reloading the database far, far easier and less error-prone.

Comment: Since Django 1.7, the `--natural` flag has been deprecated. Instead, you can use `--natural-foreign`

Comment: I used this : python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission > datadump_2.json . Still I get the error : 
ContentType matching query does not exist.: (auth.group:pk=None) field_value was '[u'add_answer', u'Evaluator', u'answer']'

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one mentioned the fact that fixture is a list that is being read from first value to last. And it's often possible that there will be a row that mentions a Primary key of a table that will be added latter.

such mistake (generating this extact issue) would look like this in a fixture:

```json
{"model": "lesson", "fields": {"class": 1}},
{
  "model": "class",
  "pk": 1
}
```

from above example you can see that `<Model> matching query query doesn't exist` (lesson cannot be added because class with pk=1 has not been added yet).
So you have to add classes before you can have lessons, so just switch them up in a fixture.

Answer (score 1):

You can check manually every ContentType table in your db or:

- If your tables are empty, deletes the tables of your models in your db et re-run syncdb (only if your in development)

Or you can use one of the Django migration tools:

- the accessible [django-evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/)
- Or the more complex [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, this error is caused when your fixture contains references to a model that doesn't exist, either because it hasn't been installed or its app hasn't been added your your INSTALLED_APPS. Unfortunately, Django's error message is pretty useless when tracking this down.

If you edit the `Queryset.get` method in `django/db/models/query.py` to print out the `*args` and `**kwargs` passed, you'll get a more helpful error message like:

```
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture ... ContentType matching query does not exist. args=() kwargs={'model': u'somenewmodel', 'app_label': u'somenewapp'}
```

Then you can check that this model/app is installed or remove those records from your fixture.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me after a lot of trials. I was having a lot of trouble with groups and logs.

- While on sqllite, start server, go to admin and delete all groups. Then type the following in shell:

  **python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e
         contenttypes -e auth.Permission -e admin.Logentry > datadump_3.json**
- Change settings to MySQL in **settings.py**
- python manage.py loaddata datadump_3.json

Answer (score 0):

I found a different cause for this error, I wanted to add in case this helps anyone else. What was causing this issue for me is that I had created a group with specific permissions, and then uninstalled an app that was referenced in the group.

Specifically, I had installed reversion at one point, and created a group called "Site Editor" that gave a user permission to create, edit and delete revisions. Later I un-installed revision, but the group permissions remained when I ran the "dumpdata" command:

```
[
{
    "fields": {
        "name": "Site Editor",
        "permissions": [
            [
                "add_logentry",
                "admin",
                "logentry"
            ],
            [
                "change_logentry",
                "admin",
                "logentry"
            ],
            [
                "delete_logentry",
                "admin",
                "logentry"
            ],
            [
                "add_group",
                "auth",
                "group"
            ],
            [
                "change_group",
                "auth",
                "group"
            ],
            [
                "delete_group",
                "auth",
                "group"
            ],
            [
                "add_revision",
                "reversion",
                "revision"
            ],
            [
                "change_revision",
                "reversion",
                "revision"
            ],
            [
                "delete_revision",
                "reversion",
                "revision"
            ],
            [
                "add_version",
                "reversion",
                "version"
            ],
            [
                "change_version",
                "reversion",
                "version"
            ],
            [
                "delete_version",
                "reversion",
                "version"
            ],
            [
                "add_session",
                "sessions",
                "session"
            ],
            [
                "change_session",
                "sessions",
                "session"
            ],
            [
                "delete_session",
                "sessions",
                "session"
            ],
            [
                "add_site",
                "sites",
                "site"
            ],
            [
                "change_site",
                "sites",
                "site"
            ],
            [
                "delete_site",
                "sites",
                "site"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 2
}]
```

When I attempted to run the "loaddata" command, I kept running into this error:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: 
Problem installing fixture '/Users/me/Documents/Sites/project/path/fixtures/configuration.json': 
ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

My solution was to simply remove any reference to reversion and versions in the fixture itself, like so:

```
    [
{
    "fields": {
        "name": "Site Editor",
        "permissions": [
            [
                "add_logentry",
                "admin",
                "logentry"
            ],
            [
                "change_logentry",
                "admin",
                "logentry"
            ],
            [
                "delete_logentry",
                "admin",
                "logentry"
            ],
            [
                "add_group",
                "auth",
                "group"
            ],
            [
                "change_group",
                "auth",
                "group"
            ],
            [
                "delete_group",
                "auth",
                "group"
            ],
            [
                "add_session",
                "sessions",
                "session"
            ],
            [
                "change_session",
                "sessions",
                "session"
            ],
            [
                "delete_session",
                "sessions",
                "session"
            ],
            [
                "add_site",
                "sites",
                "site"
            ],
            [
                "change_site",
                "sites",
                "site"
            ],
            [
                "delete_site",
                "sites",
                "site"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 2
}]
```

Then I was able to import the fixture without issue.

Answer (score 0):

From django 1.7, dumpdata options have changed:
see http://polarhome.com:753/doc/python-django-doc/html/topics/serialization.html

So you an use:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary --exclude > my_fixture.json
python manage.py loaddata my_fixture.json
```

Alternatively, one can also solve the root cause: make sure the content types match in the source and destination databases. I faced the same error moving data around between databases where db1 still had content types from apps which had been removed in mean time. Importing these in db2 where the apps were never present results in this error message.

In this case, edit -at database level- the django_content_type table in db1 and remove the content types which are not in use anymore in the django application.
Then migrate or copy the data to db2 again.

If the content types are referenced in other tables, you might need to delete them there first, or use a DROP CASCADE command (risky!).

WARNING: Editing at database level is a risky business so be sure to take a backup before engaging, and don't do this on production databases.

Depending on the database type, you'll need a different tool to make the edit.

```
mysql -> [MySQLWorkBench][1]
postgres -> [pgAdmin][2] 
SQLite -> [SQLite Browser][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently changed to use `postgres` from `mysql`?

When querying the `contenttypes` with something like:

```
entry_content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
    app_label="entries", model="Entry"
)
```

This fails because in `postgres`; `app_label` and `model` are all lower case fields. So make use of the `__iexact` field lookup which will ignore case.

```
entry_content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
    app_label__iexact="entries", model__iexact="Entry"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the points made in the answers above helped point me to the correct solution for my situation as well.

The problem showed for me while rebuilding Elasticsearch indexes.

Ultimately problem was a FK reference to a non-existant record. How that got there in the first place is still a mystery but creating the record referred to by the foreign key got the process running again.